# Keep formatting from being stripped from JSON in Angular from Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase

I have an application connected to Firebase and displayed with an ng-repeat, see code below.  The connection works and displays, but the description item has a \n inline to create separate paragraphs, which unfortunately is being stripped out and the paragraphs simple print to page as one big paragraph.  I am currently using Angular 1.3.8.  I've tried ngSanitize and its either not working or I am using it incorrectly.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
<div>
    <tr ng-repeat="m in members | orderBy:'company' | filter:query">
        <td style="width:250px"><b>{{ m.company }}</b>
            <br>{{ m.address }}
            <br>{{ m.address2 }}
            <br><a href="{{ m.url }}" target="_blank">{{ m.url }}</a>
            <br>
            <br>{{ m.name }}
            <br><em>{{ m.title }}</em>
            <br>{{ m.phone }}
            <br><a mailto="{{ m.email }}">{{ m.email }}</a>
            <br>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>{{ m.description }}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: You should begin with formatting your code sample

Comment: What do you want instead of these \n? New blocks or display all inline and simply remove the \n characters?

Answer (score 3):

HTML ignores line breaks when it comes to formatting. You would need to either replace the line breaks with `<br>` elements or set `white-space` to `pre`, `pre-wrap` or `pre-line` in your CSS.

Try editing the description part like this:

HTML:

```
<td class="description">{{ m.description }}</td>
```

CSS:

```
.description {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

This will keep any line breaks in `m.description` in the HTML formatting.

Comment: Adding <br> in Firebase will literally display <br> in the description.  Tried the white-space idea, but no dice.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the extra characters using, let's call it trim in your HTML:

```
{{ trim(m.description) }}
```

And code:

```
$scope.trim = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
};
```